# Генератор и списки. Выход за длину листа. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Такое задание:

> 3. Есть два списка: tutors = [
>    'Иван', 'Анастасия', 'Петр', 'Сергей',
>    'Дмитрий', 'Борис', 'Елена' ] klasses = [
>    '9А', '7В', '9Б', '9В', '8Б', '10А', '10Б', '9А' ] Необходимо реализовать генератор, возвращающий кортежи вида (, ),
>    например: ('Иван', '9А') ('Анастасия', '7В') ... Количество
>    генерируемых кортежей не должно быть больше длины списка tutors. Если
>    в списке klasses меньше элементов, чем в списке tutors, необходимо
>    вывести последние кортежи в виде: (, None), например:
>    ('Станислав', None)

Дело в том, что я выхожу за длину и я вроде даже написал, что вот, на последний индекс класса нужно чтобы выводило (None, класс), но все равно ошибка. Мне предложили решить zip_longest(), но я либо чего-то не понял, либо не понял человек с которым мы это обсуждали, **но мне нужен именно генератор!!!** Поэтому я не очень понимаю как решить правильно, помогите пожалуйста.
**Код без зипа:**

```
tutors = [
    'Иван', 'Анастасия', 'Петр', 'Сергей',
    'Дмитрий', 'Борис', 'Елена'
]

klasses = [
    '9А', '7В', '9Б', '9В', '8Б', '10А', '10Б', '9А'
]

def gen_of_people():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i != len(klasses):
        if i == klasses[-1]:
              yield (None, klasses[i])
              i += 1
              j += 1
              break
        else:
            yield (tutors[j], klasses[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
    

for gen in gen_of_people():
    print(gen)
```

Вот картинка с ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поменяйте условие в `if` на `i >= len(tutors)`, а в `while` на `i < len(klasses)`

Comment: @danis спасибо большое!

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

tutors = [ 'Иван', 'Анастасия', 'Петр', 'Сергей', 'Дмитрий', 'Борис', 'Елена' ]
klasses = [ '9А', '7В', '9Б', '9В', '8Б', '10А', '10Б', '9А' ]

iterator = zip_longest(tutors, klasses[:len(tutors)])
print(list(iterator))
_____________________________
[('Иван', '9А'), ('Анастасия', '7В'), ('Петр', '9Б'), ('Сергей', '9В'), ('Дмитрий', '8Б'), ('Борис', '10А'), ('Елена', '10Б')]
```